# I am trying to use attributes in a chef template

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am having trouble trying to get information from a default attributes file into a template using Chef. Currently, I have this:

```
# attributes/default.rb
default['environment']['extrahosts'] = [ 'hostname1:address1', 'hostname2:address2' ]

#recipes/default.rb
extra_hosts = node[:environment][:extrahosts]

...
...
template '/blahblah' do
  source 'blahblah.erb'
  variables( :extra_hosts => extra_hosts )
end

#templates/blahblah.erb
<% for @item in @extra_hosts %>
  - <%= @item %>
<% end %>
```

Although this doesn't work. What do I add to my template to yield:

```
  - hostname1:address1
  - hostname2:address2
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you write a loop in Ruby is to use the `each` method and a block.

```
<% @extra_hosts.each do |item| %>
  - <%= item %>
<% end %>
```

Also note that the loop variable doesn't have the at sign because it isn't an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. :) That works. However, it only works if I add:
<% node[:environment][:extrahosts].each do |item| %>

It seems like my line in the recipe of :
extra_hosts = node[:environment][:extrahosts]
... isn't working to take the contents of the attributes and put them in as an array?

My templates portion reads:
template '/blahblah' do
  source 'blahblah.erb'
  variables( :extra_hosts => extra_hosts )
end

Comment: What you have is correct overall (though double check for typos) but if you are setting the node attribute via some converge-time trickery it might cause issues.

Comment: You can log the value of `extra_hosts` in your recipe code via a log resource.